# Preventing a C# System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard object from opening on double-clicking

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I use PdfSharp to create a PdfDocument object:

```
private readonly PdfDocument _pdf = new PdfDocument();
```

Along with the other methods for actually adding the text, setting font styles etc.  I then write the pdf file to a temporary location on disk:

```
 var tempPdf = string.Concat(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ".pdf");
_pdf.Save(tempPdf);
```

Which I then use in System.Windows.Clipboard class to copy the content to the clipboard:

```
Clipboard.SetFileDropList(new StringCollection {tempPdf});
```

When the user pastes the Clipboard content into a Word document for example, the pdf content appears in the document as desired.

The problem I have is that when the user double-clicks on the embedded PDF it launches the PDF in a viewer such as Adobe Reader, also as expected.  The (unanticipated) problem I have is that I need to prevent this pop-up from happening given that this content will be inserted into a legal document.

Can any suggest any approaches or strategies for helping me to achieve something like this?  To summarise - allowing them to paste [pdf] content stored in the clipboard to a Word document, but without it opening on double-clicking.

Comment: I think maybe PDF isn't the format you're looking for then... maybe use html formatted info? Word clipboard can use that too, and it just gets pasted inline instead of embedded as document to open.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I had become fixated on using PDF generation somewhat.

Comment: I mean, you have told us what you do _not_ want to happen, but you haven't actually described what you _want_ to happen. An embedded document that can _not_ be opened is rather useless.

Comment: The reason I was embedding PDF inside the Word document was primarily to prevent modification of content - which could be used to illustrate payment schedules in tabular format etc.

Comment: Isn't PDF generally a readonly  format? And it has options to lock / secure it too as far as I know. That said, anything can be duplicated and edited; there's no real way to prevent anyone from making an identical looking copy with changed data. The only think you can do is use some kind of secured document type.

Comment: I basically want to prevent it's opening on double-clicking inside the Word doc.  Convert or generate to a bitmap/image instead perhaps?  Maybe the original assumption to generate PDFs is non-optimal.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in my question ;)

And credit to [Nyerguds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395685/nyerguds) for helping me out of my cocoon - I was fixated on using PDF files to copy to the clipboard.

The solution is to replace the usages of PdfSharp for pdf generation with System.Drawing.Graphics / System.Drawing.Bitmap to create jpg images of that which we want to copy.

And once the clipboard contents have been pasted to the Word document, we no longer have that problem of the image being openable on double-clicking.